# Laptop wont boot up

Tags: boot, partitioning, startup

My laptop stopped working in the middle of me using it. I tried restarting and it sits at the Gateway logo for a while and then end up on a blue APTIO SETUP -AMI screen which I can't get beyond. It has an option to recover Windows, but does nothing when I press Enter. In the past I had a desktop that I was able to install Ubuntu on when Windows stopped working so I thought maybe that could work now too or at least tell me if it's a PC problem or a Windows problem.

I created a bootable USB, but when I try to install Ubuntu it gets hung up on the *Installation type* screen. There are no devices listed in the box. And when I click install now I get a pop-up *No root file system defined*, correct from partition menu. I quit the install menu and tried GParted, but it only shows me the USB not my hard drive. I think it's telling me the hard drive died, maybe? Do you have any guidance about whether I can repair this or if I need to buy a new PC?
*update -I bought a new ssd hard drive, put it in but still not showing up...I must be missing something.

Comment: If your hard drive is not detected by Gparted and the Ubuntu installer, it is dead. Get a new SSD and restore your data from backup. In any case, this is not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Thanks I thought I was missing a step in installing on the correct drive or something.

Comment: MIght be worth putting the drive into a usb caddy to see if it's recognised - you might find out if it's the drive itself or the connection to the motherboard that way?

Comment: Cross posted to [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1837362/167207).